# x86 INT_PTR; UINT_PTR -> x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Когда я изучал чужой код (win32), я наткнулся на такие строчки кода:

`typedef INT_PTR Tint;
typedef UINT_PTR Tuint;`

И дело в том что я когда пытался использовать эти "типы" (не знаю как называются) в своем проекте (x64), я наткнулся на то что Visual studio выдает ошибку.
Все хидеры, где определены typedef на Tint и Tuint, присутствуют, дело в том что когда я компелирую код в х64 он выдает ошибку "идентификатор "INT_PTR/UINT_PTR" не определен". Однако когда я компелирую в х86 никакой ошибки не выдает. Вопрос - как перенести идентификаторы из х86 в х64 чтобы не выдавало ошибки?

Comment: В Windows API типы `INT_PTR` и `UINT_PTR` присутствуют всегда. Поэтому с чего это вдруг вы им стали искать замену в "x64" и что такое "Visual studio выдает ошибку" - не ясно.

Comment: Приведите пример использования и ошибку.

Comment: Могу предположить, что вы не включили в свой проект хидеры, где определены typedef на Tint и Tuint. Неважно х64 или х86 проект.

Comment: @awesome, все хидеры, где определены typedef на Tint и Tuint, присутствуют, дело в том что когда я компелирую код в х64 он видает ошибку "идентификатор "INT_PTR/UINT_PTR" не определен". Однако когда я компелирую в х86 никакой ошибки не выдает. Вопрос - как перенести идентификаторы из х86 в х64 чтобы не выдавало ошибки?

Comment: В х64 INT_PTR это синоним для __int64, в х86 это синоним для int. Соотвественно UINT_PTR это синоним на беззнаковые версии типов __int64 и int. Может только, что для __int64 нужен какой-то хидер...но это не точно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Нужен микромягкий заголовочный файл basetsd.h для C.
Эти названия равносильны __int64 и unsigned __int64 соответственно в x64, а в x86 равносильны int и unsigned int соответственно

Comment: Не могли бы Вы дать более подробный ответ? Спасибо.

Comment: Типы `INT_PTR` и `UINT_PTR` не равносильны `__int64` и `unsigned __int64`.

Comment: Да, запамятовал, исправил